# Gradle Jar doesn't compile the .jar correctly?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I am using [Codenvy](http://codenvy.io), which is an Eclipse Che IDE online, to build a Java app. I have my source code in `src/main/java/App.java`. `App.java` contains 2 classes.

When I run `gradle build` it compiles the classes and makes a `App.jar` file from them. When I run `java -jar App.jar` it gives me an error: `no manifest attribute, in App.jar`

I tried making a `src/main/resources` folder and putting a `MANIFEST.MF` file in there, but it still doensn't work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `MainClass` in your `build.gradle` file -

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.something.MainClass'
    }
}
```

Comment: @PranavAvva You can define it where you want. Mainly, it should go after plugin declaration

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!